# How to give jquery validation in front end in asp .net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new asp .net mvc 4.

I have developed a page .

**View**

```
 <th colspan="4">
   <div class="row">
      @Html.TextBox("empname", (string)ViewBag.empname, new { @readonly = "readonly", id = "txtfirstName" })
    <br />
   @Html.CheckBox("txtChangePrintName", new { @id = "checkbox1" })Will you want to change the print name ?
  <br />
  <div id="textboxshow">
   FirstName @Html.TextBox("empname", (string)ViewBag.empname, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "hidden" })
  Last Name @Html.TextBox("emplastname", (string)ViewBag.emplastname, new { @class = "hidden" })
    <span style="color:red"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtLastName)</span>
```

**model**

```
 [RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z]{1,10})", ErrorMessage = "Please enter last name in between 1 to 10 characters.")]
    public string txtLastName { get; set; }
```

This page is working fine.
I have one text box that is first ,in that text box i am retrieving the firstname from db which is readonly.

Below one check box is there if he will click on that check box then two text box will come 
first is textbox which is readonly(it is retrieving the first name) and the second one is retrieving the second name which is editable .I want to give the validation to this  textbox.

How to give validation to this textbox using jquery in front end. 
This page is working fine.(the above code is working fine if it is normal textbox means not retrieving any value from db then model validation is working fine)

Comment: _The above code is_ **not** _working fine_ and shows a lack of understanding of the basics of MVC and model binding. Your not even binding anything to your property `txtLastName` so how would you ever get validation. Include you GET and POST methods and any scripts in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtLastName )
```

Comment: yes both i have used ,,,i think u didnt get my question

Comment: change  @Html.TextBox("emplastname", (string)ViewBag.emplastname, new {@class = "hidden" }) to @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtLastName , new { @class = "hidden" })

Comment: if i will do like this then it is not retrieving the data fromdb

Comment: @Cool Do you mean when you click on the CheckBox, you will have a ajax call to server to retrieve first name and last name from db? Or the first name and last name are retrieved from db in your action?